# wsdl2perl doesn't generate classes

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I have tried to generate classes for WSDL (I need complex types classes)

[--> WSDL here <--](http://webapi.aukro.cz/uploader.php?wsdl)

but have many errors:

```
found unrecognised attribute {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}arrayType (ignored) at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Base.pm line 130.
found unrecognised attribute {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}arrayType (ignored) at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Base.pm line 130.
found unrecognised attribute {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}arrayType (ignored) at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Base.pm line 130.
found unrecognised attribute {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}arrayType (ignored) at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Base.pm line 130.
Creating complexType class MyTypes/AddressInfoStruct.pm 
Creating complexType class MyTypes/AddressUserDataStruct.pm 
Creating complexType class MyTypes/AddressesInfoStruct.pm 
/usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD\complexType.tt undef error - no node  at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/Plugin/XSD.pm line 55
    SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::Plugin::XSD::create_xsd_name('SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::Plugin::XSD=SCALAR(0xa17155c)', '') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType/attributeSet.tt line 42
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType/attributeSet.tt line 42
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType/attributeSet.tt line 6
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType/attributeSet.tt line 7
    Template::Document::__ANON__('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Document.pm line 151
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Document.pm line 149
    Template::Document::process('Template::Document=HASH(0xa15ead4)', 'Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 347
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 321
    Template::Context::process('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)', 'complexType/attributeSet.tt', undef, 'localize me!') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 409
    Template::Context::include('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)', 'complexType/attributeSet.tt') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType/contentModel.tt line 19
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType/contentModel.tt line 7
    Template::Document::__ANON__('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Document.pm line 151
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Document.pm line 149
    Template::Document::process('Template::Document=HASH(0xa149910)', 'Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 347
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 321
    Template::Context::process('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)', 'complexType/contentModel.tt', undef, 'localize me!') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 409
    Template::Context::include('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)', 'complexType/contentModel.tt') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType.tt line 18
    eval {...} called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD/complexType.tt line 7
    Template::Document::__ANON__('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Document.pm line 151
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Document.pm line 149
    Template::Document::process('Template::Document=HASH(0xa157e18)', 'Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 347
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Context.pm line 321
    Template::Context::process('Template::Context=HASH(0xa171728)', 'Template::Document=HASH(0xa157e18)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Service.pm line 94
    eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template/Service.pm line 91
    Template::Service::process('Template::Service=HASH(0xa170bd4)', 'complexType.tt', 'HASH(0xa157558)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/Template.pm line 66
    Template::process('Template=HASH(0xa170da0)', 'complexType.tt', 'HASH(0xa157558)', 'MyTypes/AddressesInfoStruct.pm') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template.pm line 66
    SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::_process('SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD=SCALAR(0x9f2a628)', 'complexType.tt', 'HASH(0x9f38434)', 'MyTypes/AddressesInfoStruct.pm') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD.pm line 232
    SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD::visit_XSD_ComplexType('SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD=SCALAR(0x9f2a628)', 'SOAP::WSDL::XSD::ComplexType=SCALAR(0x9b309d0)') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Base.pm line 62
    SOAP::WSDL::Base::_accept('SOAP::WSDL::XSD::ComplexType=SCALAR(0x9b309d0)', 'SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD=SCALAR(0x9f2a628)') called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD.pm line 90
    SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD::generate_typelib('SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD=SCALAR(0x9f2a628)', undef) called at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Generator/Template/XSD.pm line 76
    SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD::generate('SOAP::WSDL::Generator::Template::XSD=SCALAR(0x9f2a628)') called at /usr/bin/wsdl2perl line 151
 at /usr/share/perl5/SOAP/WSDL/Base.pm line 62
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Who knows? It's hard to reverse engineer code *and* data from an error dump.

Comment: The code is http://p3rl.org/wsdl2perl.pl

Answer (score 0):

Basically, SOAP::WSDL is currently unable to parse WSDL, this is a bug that's already been logged [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3035942&group_id=111978&atid=660924) so I think the best option would be to try and use SOAP::Lite or create the WSDL classes manually?!